# Subversionのバージョン管理外ファイルを削除する

Tags: svn

作業コピーをリポジトリと完全に同期したい場合はバージョン管理外ファイルやディレクトリの削除を行う必要がありますが、コマンドはどう打てば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

下記のコマンドでバージョン管理外ファイルが削除出来ます

```
svn status | grep ^? | cut -c9- | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: 無視リストにあるファイルも削除対象としたい場合のパターン `svn --no-ignore status | grep '^[?I]' | cut -c9- | xargs rm -rf` もあるとさらによいと思います。